# ReactJs: Let submit button auto triggered for once then disable it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, button

I want to get [myData] from an API for once when page load.
My plan is using a hidden button, make it auto-trigger.
But my problem is that the button keep triggering.

How to change my code to make it auto-triggered once.

My Code:

```
state = {myData: ''}
config = () => {
   axios.get('http://mySite')
   .then(res => this.setState({myData: res.data}))
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <button style={{visibility:'hidden'}} onClick={this.config()}></button>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Try changing  ```onClick={this.config()}``` to ```onClick={this.config}``` .. Remove paranthesis ```()``` after function name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your config function inside componentDidMount, it will be called only when the page loaded. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount